# How to return compressed response in IBM Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I have an HTTP enabled function, Node.js, that returns a big JSON (about 1.2 MB). Is there any way to compress that before sending to browser? I'm aware of Node module [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib), but I'm wondering if there is a predefined way to do that in actions.
I haven't found anything about it in IBM or OpenWhisk docs

**EDIT:**
In my tests I have inspected request headers, the browser offers `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br` as usual

Comment: Do you want the client to transparently receive the compressed results or require the client to decompress them in the client app? Shouldn't that be handled in the transport layer itself?

Comment: @data_henrik yes, I need something like  `Content-Encoding: gzip` , and then on client side decompress the data. It's just for saving bandwidth... By the way, I know I can write myself some sort of "middleware" before  returning response. Actually, automatic response type is `application/json`